# Pathfinder - Why are there more than one BAB indicators on the class tables?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

For example:
The BAB for a level 15 fighter would be +15/+10/+5 and I dont know why there are more than one. I am using the core rule book btw.

Comment: Technically this question is not the same as the linked one, but the linked question is an answer to this one.

Comment: Honestly there should be another option to mark a question as 'similar answer' but not duplicate. I'd say right now it would've been better to simply comment 'relevant: (link)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a character has reaches certain amounts of Base Attack Bonus (+6, +11 or +16) they receive an additional attack as part of a full attack each round. Subsequent attacks are made at a cumulative -5 penalty to their Base Attack Bonus

> **[Base Attack Bonus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Attack-Bonus)**
>
> A base attack bonus is an attack roll bonus derived from character class and level or creature type and Hit Dice
> (or combination's thereof). Base attack bonuses increase at different
> rates for different character classes and creature types. **A second
> attack is gained when a base attack bonus reaches +6, a third with a
> base attack bonus of +11 or higher, and a fourth with a base attack
> bonus of +16 or higher.** Base attack bonuses gained from different
> sources, such as when a character is a multiclass character, stack.

In your example, the Fighter would be able to make three attacks as part of a [full attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Full-Attack), one at +15 BAB, one at +10 BAB and one at +5 BAB.

You must use the full attack action to make use of these extra attacks.

> If you get more than one attack per round because your base attack
> bonus is high enough ...
> you must use a full-round action to get your additional attacks.

Comment: You might want to not write "BAB (+6/+11/+16)" in your answer, as that looks deceptively similar to the +15/+10/+5 in the question.